# cannot read property of undefined - RENDER (input)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My program is a modification form.

I want to fill the tag  with the value nom of my object:
*(nom: {id: "1", nom: "ENV"})*

So I put in my *this.state = {nom: ''}*

I fill it with the function:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(() => ({ nom: this.props.store.environnements.find (p => p.id == this.props.environnement.match.params.id) }));
}
```

In my render () function, I entered in my  
value = {this.state.nom.nom}
my page it correctly displays the name in the input.

But when I do a refresh, I get an error in the console:

**"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nom' of undefined
    at EditEnvironnementForm.render"**

Could you help me solve this problem? Thank you!

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

export class EditEnvironnementForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            nom: '',
            error: ''
        };
        this.onNomChange = this.onNomChange.bind(this);
        this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    onNomChange(e) {
        const nom = e.target.value;
        console.log(nom)
        this.setState(() => ({ nom: nom }));
    }

    onSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if (!this.state.nom) {
            this.setState(() => ({ error: 'Please set environnement!' }));
        } else {
            this.setState(() => ({ error: '' }));
            this.props.onSubmitEnvironnement(
                {
                    nom: this.state.nom,
                }
            );
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState(() => ({ nom: this.props.store.environnements.find (p => p.id == this.props.environnement.match.params.id) }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                {console.log(this.state.nom)}
                {this.state.error && <p className='error'>{this.state.error}</p>}
                <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit} className='add-book-form'>

                    <input type="text" placeholder="nom" autoFocus
                        value={this.state.nom.nom}
                        onChange={this.onNomChange} />
                    <br />
                    <button>Add Environnement</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        store: state
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(EditEnvironnementForm);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don,t need to this.setState in componentDidMount its not a good practice if you want to update the state according to the upcoming props then you simple do like that.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevsProp) {
    if (prevsProp.store !== this.props.store){
       this.setState({ nom: this.props.store.environnements.find (p => p.id == this.props.environnement.match.params.id) });
    }
}
```

In render method you need to do like this.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="nom" autoFocus
   value={this.state.nom || ''}
   onChange={this.onNomChange} 
/>
```

for more information please see the link
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 1):

`Render` lifecycle method executes before `componentDidMount`.

So in your `render` :

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="nom" autoFocus
   value={this.state.nom.nom}
   onChange={this.onNomChange} />
 <br />
```

`this.state.nom` is equal to a string (as you assigned it in the constructor) in the fist render. Then you set the `this.state.nom` to object through the `componentDidMount` but the first render has already failed and you get the error.
 To bypass this you have to check if `this.state.nom` is an object. Something like this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="nom" autoFocus
   value={this.state.nom ? this.state.nom.nom : ''}
   onChange={this.onNomChange} 
/>
```

Comment: I just tried using this but i get: : TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Comment: What is the result of `{console.log(this.state.nom)}` in your render?

Comment: undefined and after : {id: 15, nom: "RECT"}

Comment: Try changing the input value to the following then `this.state.nom ? this.state.nom.nom : ''`. This way you'll check if the state has `nom` at all. If not pass empty string as default value.

Comment: Thank, with this technique, I have no more errors and it is displayed correctly. However when I refresh the page, I get an empty input

Comment: Can you try setting up a codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21 ?

Comment: Sorry but it's not easy to implement on codesandbox ... :/